# Do stopwords interfere with queries that use SENTENCE in Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

I do not have Sphinx installed yet I am still reviewing if it makes sense so pardon a question I could probably answer on my own otherwise.

If I had the period as a stopword (so I can match e.g. U.S. to US) will a query that uses SENTENCE? In other words will the query ignore the period because of stopword and thus fail to recognize the end of sentence boundary?

Comment: You appear to be using the 'stopword' to mean something different to what i means in sphinx. Possibly talking about 'ignore_chars' instead? As the sentance detection happens in the HTML stripper, it should apply before ignore_chars, so in threory shgould be able to use ignore_chars for this and SENTENCE at the same time.

Comment: @barryhundter: From SphinxSearch: "Stopwords are the words that will not be indexed. Typically you'd put most frequent words in the stopwords list because they do not add much value to search results but consume a lot of resources to process." So I thought it would be e.g. And, The, of so they don't get indexed and thus you can match w/o without them. That was my idea for the period too. They say ignore-cars will index abc-def as abcdef. I'll need to test I guess since they seem similar to me.

Comment: Notice its stopWORDS, vs ignore_CHARS. One is whole words, vs just charactors within words. Words (or tokens in sphinx parlance) are an important concept. http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2014/11/26/sphinx-text-processing-pipeline/

Comment: @barryhunter Thanks for the clarification. stopwords then is "the", "of", etc and ignore_CHARS is for hypens, periods and such. I can test and update this question/thread once I have some clarify on period as ignore_CHAR vs SENTENCE query.